# Custom attribute in Bootgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-bootgrid

I need 2 things.

1. I need to set a custom attribute in tr of tbody using bootgrid.
2. I need to disable the checkbox which End user have already saved in bootgrid.[bootgrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quJzR.png)

Comment: And what have you tried so far, please show us? Stack overflow is not a coding service

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Please find the html and Javascript in the link. https://jsfiddle.net/3eu9st8e/1/